# Creating a runtime environment in php

Tags: php, xml, runtime

How would I possible use or create a runtime environment in php that will communicate constantly with the backend of HTML XML and JS XML? Basicly, how would I make a php script not die but continually running and respond to the HTML XML events requesting the php script, example `<form method="post">` is html and is using XML to send the script serverside (to php or other languages) then it refreshes to get a return statement. Normally php would die within' less then a second, but how would I make a runtime which will continually gonna stay open?

> **Note**: Using a runtime is not the same as loading the script in with the javascript interval function!
>
> Using the javascript interval and JQuery/AJAX to simply call the php script makes no different and would not be considered as a correct answer OR be correct at all, cause the interval function and the JQuery `load` function is calling the file each requested `ms`, so using those functions would not solve the php runtime mysterium!

---

This will also mean if there is a way for php to run at a html runtime and create the php runtime to work together (multitasking) then php could be a whole new type of php.. I know that didn't make any sense, but it means you can extend php so much to literally create a timer event to extend multitasking from the php side (`class timer {public function start(){ ... } public function stop(){ ... } public function interval($interval /* As Integer */){ ... } public function ON_TICK /* The event running the multitasking from php side */(){ timer::event('on_tick'); } private function event($event){ if($event==='on_tick'){ timer::executeEvent()}}; private function executeEvent($script){/*Script can include if statements and db upload, and conditions, etc*/ /* This will run the script that was called from the function, example $timer1 = new timer;$timer1->interval(1/*In ms*/);$timer1->script("if(1=1){$timer1->stop();}") */}}`)

Comment: `then php could be a whole new type of php` You got it `then` but not yet ;)   PHP is just Client-Server Request-Response on HTML level without Ajax. And on this `runtime environment` read about `statefull vs. stateless` applications

Comment: Yes it is possible, but not in the way you think. You will have to run PHP directly (outside a webserver). PHP then can start its own http/websocket server inside the process (like node.js). A websocket server will allow you a persistent connection between the client and the php process.

Comment: FYI: `example <form method="post"> is html and is using XML to send the script serverside` is a wrong statement, there is no XML that will be generated and send via/from an HTML Form :)

Comment: @ThW wouldn't that be  unsecure due to everyone will have the same php process running? since im going to run $_SESSION about user details and such, I keep everything encrypted tohough with my own algorithm.

Comment: Websockets are not AJAX (XHR). They work differently and unlike AJAX it is a single persistent connection.

Comment: @RichardOlsenSandberg yes you will have to implement a lot of stuff (security, error handling, ...) that is usually handled by the Webserver.

Comment: Websockets dont have user-sessions foreach user!